# Factory Girl, issue with InvalidRecord error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I have a problem with the error:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
```

caused by this:

```
let(:ind2){ build(:ind2) }
```

Rspec test:

```
  describe '#client_free_time_validation' do
    let(:ind) { build(:ind).tap {|e| p e.valid?; p e.errors}}
    let(:ind2){ build(:ind2).tap {|e| p e.valid?; p e.errors} }

    context 'when training is during another training' do
      it 'raises an error' do
        expect(ind.valid?).to be_truthy
        expect(ind2.valid?).to be_falsey
        # expect(ind2.errors.count).to eq 1
        # expect(ind2.errors[:base]).to eq(['Masz w tym czasie inny trening.'])
      end
    end
```

Factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :individual_training do
    date_of_training { Date.today.next_week.advance(days: 1) }
    association :client, factory: :client
    association :trainer, factory: :trainer
    start_on Time.parse('12:30')
    end_on Time.parse('13:30')
    association :training_cost, factory: :tc2

    factory :ind do
      start_on Time.parse('11:00')
      end_on Time.parse('12:00')
    end

    factory :ind2 do
      start_on Time.parse('10:30')
      end_on Time.parse('11:30')
    end
  end
end
```

I'm confused because similar `let` working in another test. I tried debugging by using `tap` method but it doesn't show error messages(in another case nice presents).

If I should put some additional data(how my model looks like etc.), please write.

I saw that if I comment the first `let` or second, the test passes. It looks at situations like two `let`(`ind` and `ind2`) couldn't work together.
Example values of attributes generate by test:

```
#<ActiveModel::Errors:0x00000001f4ade8 @base=#<IndividualTraining id: nil, date_of_training: "2016-08-23", client_id: 28, trainer_id: 29, start_on: "2016-08-20 11:00:00", end_on: "2016-08-20 12:00:00", training_cost_id: 4>, @messages={}>
```

Do you have a suggestion how to debug what record is invalid?

Update:

Full error message:

```
Failure/Error: let(:ind2){ build(:ind2).tap {|e| p e.valid?; p e.errors} }

 ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid:
   Nieprawidłowy rekord

# /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:351:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `block in transaction'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:184:in `within_new_transaction'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:213:in `transaction'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:348:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.5.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/configuration.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:15:in `create'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:12:in `block in result'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `tap'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/create.rb:9:in `result'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/build.rb:5:in `association'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:31:in `association'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute/association.rb:19:in `block in to_proc'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:75:in `instance_exec'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluator.rb:75:in `block in define_attribute'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:56:in `get'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:16:in `block (2 levels) in object'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `each'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:15:in `block in object'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `tap'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/attribute_assigner.rb:14:in `object'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/evaluation.rb:12:in `object'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy/build.rb:9:in `result'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/factory.rb:42:in `run'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:29:in `block in run'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/activesupport-4.2.5.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/factory_runner.rb:28:in `run'
     # /home/lukas/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/strategy_syntax_method_registrar.rb:20:in `block in define_singular_strategy_method'
     # ./spec/models/individual_training_spec.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
     # ./spec/models/individual_training_spec.rb:65:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

Update 2:

The error disappears when I set `date_of_training Date.today` in a factory. I also tried to set manually date like 2016-08-23, but it's still `InvalidRecord`. Also `Date.today + 1.day` not working. Any idea what can be wrong? Maybe date_of_training isn't a direct problem.

Update 3:
IndividualTraining model validations:

```
  private

  def date_and_start_on_validation
    unless start_on.blank?
      if date_of_training < Date.today
        errors.add(:base, 'You cannot set individual training before today.')
      elsif date_of_training == Date.today
        if start_on <= Time.now
          errors.add(:base, 'Time of today training is before current time.')
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # check if trainer work while will be individual_training
  def date_of_training_validation
    unless start_on.blank?
      trainer.work_schedules.each_with_index do |ti, ind|
        if ti.day_of_week == BackendController.helpers.translate_date(date_of_training)
          if (start_on.strftime('%H:%M')..end_on.strftime('%H:%M'))
             .overlaps?(ti.start_time.strftime('%H:%M')..ti.end_time.strftime('%H:%M'))
            break
          else
            errors.add(:base, 'Training is outside of trainer work schedule.')
          end
        elsif ind == trainer.work_schedules.size - 1
          errors.add(:base, 'In this day trainer doesn't work.')
        end
      end
    end
  end

  # check if client doesn't have another training or activity
  def client_free_time_validation
    unless start_on.blank?
      client.individual_trainings_as_client.where(date_of_training: date_of_training)
            .where('id != ?', id).each do |ci|
        if (start_on...end_on).overlaps?(ci.start_on...ci.end_on)
          errors.add(:base, 'You have another training.')
        end
      end
      client.activities.where(day_of_week: BackendController.helpers.translate_date(date_of_training))
            .each do |ca|
        if (start_on...end_on).overlaps?(ca.start_on...end_on)
          errors.add(:base, 'You have another activity.')
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Update 4:
I noticed that if I first execute ind.valid? - it will be true and ind2 will be RecordInvalid. But when I reload and check ind2.valid? - now it is true and ind false.

Update 5:
I used the same let but separately in a different context, and rspec passed. What could be the reason, that I cannot use two let in the same context?

IndividualTraining associations

```
  belongs_to :trainer, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'trainer_id'
  belongs_to :client, class_name: 'Person', foreign_key: 'client_id'
  belongs_to :training_cost
```

client and trainer factories

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :person do
    pesel { Faker::Number.number(11) }
    first_name 'Thomas'
    last_name 'Owel'
    date_of_birth { Faker::Time.between('1970-01-01', '2000-12-31') }
    email { Faker::Internet.email }
    password { Faker::Internet.password }
    type 'Person'
  end

  factory :client, parent: :person, class: 'Client' do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    type 'Client'
  end
  factory :trainer, parent: :person, class: 'Trainer' do
    first_name { Faker::Name.first_name }
    last_name { Faker::Name.last_name }
    type 'Trainer'
    salary { Faker::Number.decimal(4, 2) }
    hiredate { Faker::Time.between('2016-01-01', '2016-04-30') }
  end
end
```

Update 6:
In another context I have this let:

```
let(:individual_training) { build :individual_training, trainer_id: work_schedule[:person_id] }
let(:ind2) do
  build :individual_training,
        trainer_id: work_schedule[:person_id],
        date_of_training: Date.today.next_week.advance(days: 0),
        start_on: Time.now - 1.hour,
        end_on: Time.now
end
```

This nice works. There is no error: `RecordInvalid`

Comment: Are you sure that associated objects are valid?

Comment: Could you please add the full error message so we can things like line number, file, full error message, etc?

Comment: @MichałSzajbe yes I'm sure, because I checked this factories in another tests.

Comment: @kcdragon post updated. If you want some more, please write.

Comment: Please add the validations for the IndividualTraining model.

Comment: @zetetic post updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These could be the reason behind "Invalid record error" -

```
Reason - It usually happens when you use "create" and "build" together.
create method persists the instance while the build method keeps it only in memory.
```

Firstly, I will suggest you to use build method and please check validations related to it. There is something wrong in your validations.